# Pipeline order for css bundles, jquery and .js files. Error: GET .net::ERR_ABORTED 500 In css bundles. (Internal Server Error)

Tags: jquery, .net-6.0

After deploying our application, I am getting a HTTP 500 when I load this page http://vpn.myweb.com/css/bundles/admin.css and app.css for the first time. http://vpn.myweb.com/css/bundles/admin.css gives a http 500 first time and then loads correctly.
My observation in developer tools, when I load it for the first time, both app.css and admin.css are blank.
How do I make this issue happen in debug mode? It happens only for QA or prod.

```
 GET http://vpn.myweb.com/css/bundles/admin.css net::ERR_ABORTED 500 (Internal Server Error)
 GET http://vpn.myweb.com/css/bundles/app.css net::ERR_ABORTED 500 (Internal Server Error)
 GET http://vpn.myweb.com/js/bundles/modernizr.js net::ERR_ABORTED 500 (Internal Server Error)
 GET http://vpn.myweb.com/js/bundles/jquery.js net::ERR_ABORTED 500 (Internal Server Error)
 GET http://vpn.myweb.com/js/bundles/Admin.js net::ERR_ABORTED 500 (Internal Server Error)
 GET http://vpn.myweb.com/js/bundles/bootstrap.js net::ERR_ABORTED 500 (Internal Server Error)
jquery.validate.min.js:4 Uncaught ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined
```

_Layout.cshtml

```
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="~/css/bundles/app.css" />
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="~/css/bundles/admin.css" /> 
 <script src="~/js/bundles/modernizr.js"></script>
```

Program.cs

```
builder.Services.AddWebOptimizer(pipeline =>
{
    pipeline.AddJavaScriptBundle("/js/bundles/datetimepicker.js", "/js/moment.min.js", "/js/bootstrap-datetimepicker.min.js");
    pipeline.AddJavaScriptBundle("/js/bundles/dataTables.js", 
        "/js/moment.min.js",
        "/js/DataTables/jquery.dataTables.min.js",
        "/js/DataTables/dataTables.buttons.min.js",
        "/js/DataTables/jszip.min.js",
        "/js/DataTables/buttons.html5.min.js",
        "/js/DataTables/dataTables.bootstrap.min.js",
        "/js/DataTables/datetime-moment.js",
        "/js/DataTables/dataTables.select.min.js");
    pipeline.AddJavaScriptBundle("/js/bundles/modernizr.js", "/js/modernizr-2.8.3.js");
    
    pipeline.AddJavaScriptBundle("/js/bundles/jqueryval.js", "/js/jquery.validate*");
    pipeline.AddJavaScriptBundle("/js/bundles/bootstrap.js", "/js/bootstrap.min.js", "/js/respond.js");
    pipeline.AddJavaScriptBundle("/js/bundles/admin.js", "/js/AdminLTE/adminlte.js", "/js/bootbox.min.js");
    

    pipeline.AddCssBundle("/css/bundles/app.css", "/css/bootstrap.min.css", "/css/bootstrap4-classes.css", "/css/font-awesome.min.css", "/css/Site.css");
    pipeline.AddCssBundle("/css/bundles/admin.css", "/css/AdminLTE.css", "/css/skins/skin-blue.css");
    pipeline.AddCssBundle("/css/bundles/dt.css", "/datatables/css/dataTables.bootstrap.min.css", "/datatables/css/buttons.dataTables.min.css");
    pipeline.AddCssBundle("/css/bundles/datetimepicker.css", "/css/bootstrap-datetimepicker.min.css");


});
```

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This problem is usually solved by adding write permission to the AppPool user for the WebOptimizer cache directory. The cache directory can be set in appsettings.json file. See [here](https://github.com/ligershark/WebOptimizer#options) for more info

```
{
  "webOptimizer": {
    "enableCaching": true,
    "enableMemoryCache": true,
    "enableDiskCache": true,
    "cacheDirectory": "/var/temp/weboptimizercache", /*Set permission for this line*/
    "enableTagHelperBundling": true,
    "cdnUrl": "https://my-cdn.com/",
    "allowEmptyBundle": false
  }
}
```

This [link](https://www.nopcommerce.com/en/boards/topic/94688/unexpected-path-generated-at-linux) may also help for setting permissions on Linux. Also some people say you should give write permission to all script/css folders, but documents and my experience do not confirm that.